# Float number and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT `g`.`id` , 
    `g`.`steam_id` , 
    `g`.`type` , 
    `g`.`title` ,
    `g`.`price` , 
    `g`.`metascore` , 
    `g`.`image` ,
    (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM `game_promotions`
        WHERE `game_promotions`.`game_id` = `g`.`id`
    ) AS `promotion_id`,
    (

        SELECT `price`
        FROM `game_promotions`
        WHERE `game_promotions`.`game_id` = `g`.`id`
    ) AS `promotion_price`, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT( `id` )
        FROM `bot_games`
        WHERE `game_id` = `g`.`id`
        AND `buyer` IS NULL
    ) AS `copies`
FROM 
    `games` AS `g` , 
    `game_genres` AS `gg`
WHERE
    `gg`.`game_id` = `g`.`id`
    AND `g`.`title` LIKE "Counter%"
GROUP BY `promotion_id`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And problem is bad returned `promotion_price`. In `game_promotions` table, `price` is "24.99", but in query result `promotion_price` is "14.9899997711182". The returned promotion ID is good. Only float price is invalid. Why this number has changed?

Comment: probably because 14.99 cannot be represented accurately in floating point. not many numbers CAN be. e.g. "we are floating point of borg, prepare to be approximated".

Comment: how is defined the price column? INT or FLOAT or what ?

Comment: Price column is defined FLOAT

Comment: Do you mean the result is 24.9899997711182? That's within the single precision float margin of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but I'm posting my modified query below. First of all, I got rid of the implicit join and changed it with an explicit `INNER JOIN`. I also moved your subquerys with  `LEFT JOIN`s for better performance. And I deleted the `DISTINCT` and the `GROUP BY` because I couldn't really understand why you needed them.

```
SELECT 
    `g`.`id` , 
    `g`.`steam_id` , 
    `g`.`type` , 
    `g`.`title` ,
    `g`.`price` , 
    `g`.`metascore` , 
    `g`.`image`,
    `gp`.`id` AS `promotion_id`,
    `gp`.`price` AS `promotion_price`, 
    `bg`.`copies`
FROM 
    `games` AS `g`
INNER JOIN `game_genres` AS `gg`
    ON `gg`.`game_id` = `g`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `game_promotions` as `gp`
    ON `g`.`id` = `gp`.`game_id`
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `game_id`, COUNT(`id`) `copies`
            FROM `bot_games`
            WHERE `buyer` IS NULL
            GROUP BY `game_id`) `bg`
    ON `bg`.`game_id` = `g`.`id`
WHERE `g`.`title` LIKE "Counter%"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the result is 24.9899997711182? That's within the single precision float margin of error.

You get the expected result, you just have to round it to two decimals for display.